# C++ that can copy from text file and paste to open word program

Tags: c++, ms-word

Heres my problem. I have data.txt file with 100 lines of string. I need to paste each individual line to an open microsoft word window(or any other open window). I know how to open and read file but I dont know how to handle the microsoft word part. Im starting to program in C++  and really need some help.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: This is nontrivial. Maybe not the best start if you're just learning C++ because most of what you'll need for this is APIs for your operating system (Windows or Mac) to manipulate the clipboard and select open windows.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to learn by creating usable program related to my new job. I have a C# program already but somehow its very slow. Thats the reason I wanted to learn C++. I have another program in C# and I was able to make a C++ version of it the in terms of speed, C++ is 60% faster.

Comment: I did something similar with text files & Microsoft Excel files. the way I work with those Excel files was like this: I changed the format to .csv & run the code on those .csv files. It was long time ago (one of my 2nd year courses in C) & I don't remember the details 100%, but I think that you need to look for a way to find some format that your program look at your Word files as a text file (like .csv for Excel files). That's not solve youre problem but I hope it gives you some direction.

Comment: The challenge I have is that I have to paste line by line from a text file and paste it to another open window or application with an entry or input box. I need to find a C++ or C implementation because it much faster than what I have in C# now.

Comment: 1. you can google it & maybe you will find something similar (hard to believe) OR
2. write some code by your own. after you write it, post here your code, with a sepecific problems & difficulties to let the great minds here help you find a solution.

Comment: It's unlikely the C++ version will be much faster than the C# version, I'm afraid. Almost all your time is likely going into the OS calls: saving the text to the clipboard, finding the open MS Word window, and issuing the "paste". You may be able to cache the open window handle(s) to speed it up, but that's not language-related.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a C# version, then you're probably on Windows. So look into these calls:

- FindWindowEx: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexa
- Clipboard functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard